# GPIO pin for usb2.0 power defaults to low.

Tags: linux, usb

first time posting. So thank you for the support in advance. I'm working with an IMX6 board, running a linux kernel, u-boot, and rootfs that were generated from yocto. I used one of the core images. core-image-minimal-dev to build the kernel image. I added in usbutils to as an image_install within the core-image-minimal-dev recipe.

for my device tree I have the following for the USB
regulators

```
reg_usb_h1_vbus: regulator@1 {
                        compatible = "regulator-fixed";
                        reg = <1>;
                        regulator-name = "usb_h1_vbus";
                        regulator-min-microvolt = <5000000>;
                        regulator-max-microvolt = <5000000>;
                        gpio = <&gpio6 15 0>;

                        enable-active-high;
                };
```

and

```
&usbh1 {
        vbus-supply = <&reg_usb_h1_vbus>;
        dr_mode="peripheral";
        status = "okay";
};
```

so when i power up and get access to terminal on the surface it works fine. However, I need to manipulate the gpio6_IO15 pin to high. As this pin is responsible for powering my usb2.0 port.

when I attempt to run

```
echo 175 > /sys/class/gpio/export
```

i get an error stating that the device or resource is busy.

so I ran a check to see what it was being used by.

```
cat /sys/kernel/debug/gpio
```

well it seems by adding the above to the dts, I've allocated the resource to the kernel. Ideally I would like to use the gpio pin as a sort of power on power off for the device that is going to be connected to the usb port. However, for now I would just really like to be able to get the power on.

Whats odd is even though I have the DTS set to active high, its driving the pin low. Does anyone have any insight as to what changes could solve my situation.

Comment: I have no idea what is the meaning of your code for "regulator@1", but setting min and max for precisely the same value is at least unphysical, no regulator can be that perfect. Are you sure that your code generates any meaningful executable and not some nonsense?

Comment: So the code that I posted is part of the device tree regulators. This was setup based on a reference board, sabrea board, with similar characteristics of the board I'm using. So I'm assuming that because that it was running on the reference board with these settings it should be fine regarding the min/max. Changes I made from the reference board are regarding the gpio pin being utilized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to track down the schematic to the board I'm using and noticed that 5v power supply was turned off by default. So while I need gpio pin for the USB2.0 device to be available to toggle, the 5v supply was what was keeping me from powering on the device.

So the power issue has been resolved. I'll post another question another time to get control of the gpio pin for usb2.0 back.

I can't just use the 5v because the 5v powers multiple devices, which I don't need/want to be activated at the same time.